# "NotSupportedException" when WebRequest is unable to find a creator for that prefix

Tags: mono, httpwebrequest, servicestack, xsp

I have a really strange problem with `WebRequest` in a `ServiceStack` web application (hosted by XSP on Mono).
It seems that the registration of request modules works in a very strange way; I am using `WebRequest` to create an HTTP request, and it is failing because it was not able to find a creator for that "prefix" (HTTP).

The exception I am seeing is `NotSupportedException`, and I was able to track it to the fact that no creator is registered for the HTTP prefix (I am hitting https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebRequest.cs, around line 479)

**EDIT:** more details: `NotSupportedException` is thrown by `WebRequest.GetCreator`, which uses the URL prefix as a key to choose which creator to return; in my case, a `HttpRequestCreator`. The exception is thrown because there is no creator registered for the "HTTP" prefix (actually, there are no creators at all).

So I searched around a little bit, dug into Mono sources, and found that modules are (or should be) added to the `webRequestModules` section of `system.web` in one of the various **.config* files.

I looked at my *machine.config* file, and there it is:

```
System.Net.HttpRequestCreator, System, Version=4.0.0.0
```

Looking at [WebRequest Mono sources](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebRequest.cs)
it seems that prefixes are added from configuration(s) inside the class static constructor (not a good choice, IMHO, but still.. it should work).

To test it, I tried to add an `HttpRequestCreator` to `system.net/webRequestModules` in my `web.config`; this is loaded by XSP/Mono and results in a duplicate key exception (which is expected since `HttpRequestCreator` should be already loaded, as it is already present in *machine.config*).

**Even stranger:** if I add a mock handler for Http, like this:

```
bool res = System.Net.WebRequest.RegisterPrefix ("http", new MyHttpRequestCreator ());
Debug.Assert (res == false);
```

The assertion sometimes pass... sometimes not!
(`RegisterPrefix` returns "false" if a creator for the same prefix is already registered; I expect it always to return false, but this is not the case! Again, it is completely random)

When the registration "fails" (i.e., returns false because an "HTTP" prefix is already registered), then the `WebRequest` can create requests for HTTP. It is as if calling `RegisterPrefix` "wakes up" the static constructor and let it run.

**I am perplexed**: it seems like a race condition in the execution of the static constructor of `WebRequest`, but this does not make sense (the runtime protects static constructors with a lock, IIRC)

What am I missing?
How could I solve or work around this problem?
Is it my fault (misunderstanding or missing something), or does it look like a Mono bug, so should I submit it?

Details:

> mono --version
> Mono JIT compiler version 3.0.6 (Debian 3.0.6+dfsg-1~exp1~pre1)

Possibly related, unanswered question:

- [HTTP protocol not supported in WebRequest under mono](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17427255/863564)

Comment: Mono's WebRequest is buggy. Use HttpClient instead. Report bug to Mono project.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this hacky workaround on this issue:**

```
private static HttpWebRequest CreateWebRequest(Uri uri)
{   
   var type = Type.GetType("System.Net.HttpRequestCreator, System, Version=4.0.0.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089");
   var creator = Activator.CreateInstance(type,nonPublic:true) as IWebRequestCreate;
   return creator.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are experiencing a race condition in the execution of the static constructor of the WebRequest class. This could be caused by a variety of factors, including incorrect synchronization of access to shared resources, or the use of uninitialized variables.

One potential solution to this problem could be to ensure that the WebRequest class is initialized before attempting to use it. This can be done by accessing a static field or method of the WebRequest class before making any requests. For example:

```
int dummy = WebRequest.DefaultMaximumErrorResponseLength;
```

This will force the static constructor to run, ensuring that the WebRequest class is properly initialized before you attempt to make any requests.

Alternatively, you could try using the Lazy class to initialize the WebRequest class in a thread-safe manner. This can be done as follows:

```
private static readonly Lazy<int> DefaultMaximumErrorResponseLength =
new Lazy<int>(() => WebRequest.DefaultMaximumErrorResponseLength);

// ...

int dummy = DefaultMaximumErrorResponseLength.Value;
```

This will ensure that the WebRequest class is initialized in a thread-safe manner, without the risk of race conditions.