# NotSupportedException when downloading file

Tags: c#, webclient, notsupportedexception

Currently, I have a service running on my Mac written in C# located in `usr/local/program`. This service is capable of detecting when it needs updates by checking the version number against a server version number. The update method is run, however there always is an exception when it tries to download the `update.xml` file that contains the information and what files to download. Here is the exception that we have gotten from our custom logger:

```
11:09:46 AM [Debug] Exception Type: WebException
11:09:46 AM [Debug] Stack Trace for above:
  at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile (System.Uri address, System.String fileName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile (System.String address, System.String fileName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Net.WebClient:DownloadFile (string,string)
  at dabler.Client.ClientService.tryUpdate () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
11:09:46 AM [Debug] System.NotSupportedException: http://www.website.com/updates/client/update.xml
  at System.Net.WebRequest.GetCreator (System.String prefix) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.WebRequest.Create (System.Uri requestUri) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebRequest (System.Uri address) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.WebClient.SetupRequest (System.Uri uri) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFileCore (System.Uri address, System.String fileName, System.Object userToken) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile (System.Uri address, System.String fileName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I have researched this and according to the documentation I found, the NotSupportedException means that "The method has been called simultaneously on multiple threads." However, this is the first time that the service has ever even attempted to download a file, so I don't understand how this would be happening. One possibility I thought of would be the fact that it is trying to download the file to `usr/local/program/update.xml` but I gave the program root access to that folder.

Comment: The `NotSupportedException` is actually being thrown from `WebRequest.GetCreator`. That method appears to be Mono-specific, and is thrown if the URI prefix is not found. See source at https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebRequest.cs. Not sure why this would happen, though: "http://" looks like a valid URI prefix to me.

Comment: @pmcoltrane currently I have the service installed on two computers. One computer already had mono installed at 3.2.6 while the one that does not work contains 3.4.0. Is there a difference between those when it comes to that WebRequest.cs?

Comment: None that I can see. After doing some additional searching, I believe these questions are related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17427255/http-protocol-not-supported-in-webrequest-under-mono http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17657145/troubles-using-webrequest-in-mono?lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. The reason it wasn't working is because the program was built using 3.2.6 and I was trying to run it on a machine with 3.4.0. There doesn't seem to be any differences that I could tell between WebRequest.cs, but the building in a lower version was definitely the issue.